# Newly installed programs in Server 2016 can't be clicked from the start menu

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

I created a new instance of Windows Server Datacenter 2016 on AWS (Version: 1607 OS Build 14393.321). When I install a new application and try to click on it from the start menu it does not work.

This seems to be the exact same [issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9569b4d2-1ee1-4f23-840e-0284a4002e1f/start-menu-issue-can-not-click-on-the-newly-installed-program?forum=WinServerPreview) another user was having.

Please ignore the awesome paint job for the cursor. The screenshot did not include the cursor.

Here is how I would expect it to work:
[image: Working]

Here is what I see for newly installed applications (Notice the row is not highlighted and you cannot click:
[image: Not Working]

Comment: Certain programs cannot be run using the built-in Administrator account. Create a new account (with local administrator rights if desired) and use that.

Comment: I am able to run them if I browse to the location manually. Just not from the start menu. The account that is logged in is a domain administrator but not the local administrator account.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you ever able to get it resolved, or is the separate account the only way?